# What is the true number of confirmations before a LTC mined block moves out of the immature state?

Tags: litecoin, mining-reward, immature-coins

I've read it's 100, 101, 120...

I have a mined block that has more than 140 confirmations but is still displayed as "immature" by the wallet.

How many confirmations are required before it leaves the immature state?  Is this number variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

100​. You could argue 120 too. It's the same as Bitcoin.

```
static const int COINBASE_MATURITY = 100;
```

<sub>[Source](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master/src/main.h#L37)</sub>

Now, this is the amount of time before other nodes will let you spend your mining income. However, the client will wait 120 blocks before telling you that the generation has matured.

```
int CMerkleTx::GetBlocksToMaturity() const
{
    if (!IsCoinBase())
        return 0;
    return max(0, (COINBASE_MATURITY+20) - GetDepthInMainChain());
}
```

<sub>[Source](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L697)</sub>